# HTTP 405 when using jQuery function; sending OPTIONS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

I've come across a very strange issue. The following jQuery receives an HTTP 405 error code and sends an OPTIONS request method instead of a GET.

```
function GetPerf() 
{
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    leInterval = setInterval(function()
    {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/PerfMon3/api/performance/categories",
        data: { machine_name : "CLOUDMACHINE" },
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            WriteResponse(data);
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    },
    1000)
}
```

The interesting part is that this works perfectly fine in Internet Explorer, but Chrome I get a 405. Does anyone know what's going on?

Additional note:
It works perfectly fine regardless of browser when running it from the browser with IIS where the application is hosted. This problem only comes into play from remote machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just love finding out the answer to the issue with my own testing right after asking it on SO. I'm sorry about that, guys.

I changed the url line in the jQuery to

```
url: "http://cloudmachine/PerfMon3/api/performance/categories"
```

and now it works perfectly fine.

Still, why did it originally work only in IE? It doesn't make sense.